# Laravel 7 with Webpack and importing JS with ES Modules

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

Laravel 7, using Webpack and importing JS with ES Modules. I want to use webpackChunkNames and import JS files only when needed.

I want to export JS files from resources/js/  (for the main app.js) and other pages in the folder resources/js/pages/   ...to public/js/  and public/js/pages

My webmix looks like this:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
     output: {
       filename:'[name].js',
       chunkFilename: '[name].js',
     },
  })
  .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .js('resources/js/pages/forgot-password-module.js', 'public/js/pages/')
```

I include my app.js in my header like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

My app.js will import the additional JS file only when it is on the page, eg (slightly edited for simplicity):

```
   //jsfileneeded == for example "forgot-password-module.js"....

   if( jsfileneeded != "" ){

     import(
      /* webpackChunkName: "js/pages/[request]" */
      /* webpackMode: 'lazy' */
      '../js/pages/' + jsfileneeded
                )
                .then( module => {
                   module.default();
                } )
                .catch(error => { console.log( error ); } 
      );
   }
```

This works on the website which we'll call "www.examplesite.com", eg:

[www.examplesite.com/js/apps.js](http://www.examplesite.com/js/apps.js)
[www.examplesite.com/js/pages/forgot-password-module.js](http://www.examplesite.com/js/pages/forgot-password-module.js)

However, the same website can also be loaded through a reverse web proxy. Specifically `www.anotherexamplesite.com/extra-path`.

The "extra-path" part of the new name is causing issues, because it is a virtual folder, it doesn't exist. so immediately this doesn't work:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

I tried changing the app.js request like this:

```
    @if(domain is the other one)
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/extra-path/js/app.js"></script>
    @endif
```

This works but now it doesn't call the additional JS file, because of the folder structure of this domain versus the original. It's ignoring the virtual directory.

So how do I get Webpack to reference the correct directory structure for the JS files for both `www.examplesite.com` and `www.anotherexamplesite.com/extra-path`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial answer, but not particularly the one I had hoped for.
Given that the files are found and loaded correctly from the main domain ([www.examplesite.com](http://www.examplesite.com) in this case), and not from [www.anotherexamplesite.com/extra-path](http://www.anotherexamplesite.com/extra-path) , the solution was to modify the publicPath in webmix, to target the first domain.

```
  mix
  .webpackConfig({
     output: {
         publicPath: 'https://www.examplesite.com/'
     }
  })
```

This then imports the js files from the main domain, and not the secondary domain.

So it works, but it's not ideal.